# Oracle InvalidOperationException - When trying to select from a table

Tags: c#, oracle

I've got a parameters table where I've got a parameter to say whether my program should run, I'm trying to get this value to check for a function.

Here is the function

```
    private static bool shouldRun()
    {
        OracleCommand c = conn.CreateCommand();

        c.CommandText = "select value from parameters where lower(name) = lower('valuetocheck')"; // this one doesn't work
        //c.CommandText = "select 'Y' from dual"; - This one works
        c.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        OracleDataReader dr = c.ExecuteReader();

        dr.Read();

        string s = dr.GetString(0); // exception on this line

        return false;
    }
```

The additional information is below:

> Invalid operation on a closed object

I've tried selecting from dual, as you can see above, which works perfectly fine, but when I try to run the actual query it doesn't like it. I've checked the query in SQL Developer and it works fine.

I've had a look around SO and other websites and the only information I could get on this issue was that the command wasn't associated with a connection, which as you can see above it is.

I've also tried just doing

```
OracleCommand c;
c.Connection = conn;
```

Which also doesn't work.

Any insight into this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the username, the one listed in the connection string that you are actually using, does have privileges to read the parameters table?

Comment: I'm such an idiot! I copied the connection string from another program which uses a different User. I hadn't changed the user... Oops.

Comment: @ZachRoss-Clyne So this problem is no longer reproducible?

Comment: @DStanley - Of course it would be reproducible - just change the username back to the wrong one.  The benefit to future users of SO is that when Oracle says "Invalid operation on a closed object", more often than not, it is just confused and really should be saying 'invalid access privileges', and the programmer should check that instead.

Comment: As a matter of good practice, ALWAYS check the return value of the OracleDataReader.Read method. In your case, dr.Read() would have returned false, and thus you wouldn't have tried to invoke dr.GetString() on a reader that has no data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Oracle gives this error - "Invalid Operation on a closed object", more often than not, what actually happens is that the user does not have access privileges to the objects they are trying to access in the database.  Check your connection string and make absolutely sure that the user listed in that connection string does have privileges to the objects in your query - in this case, read access to the Parameters table.

Comment: Change it how? Can you be more specific so that this answer is useful to others?

Comment: @DStanley - you are right.  The details to the answer really were in the comments I made to the OP's question, but they needed to be put here so they are easier to find.  I hope it's better now.

Comment: I get this error on a long-running task, doing DB operaitions, after some time (30+ minutes). So no reason to think it has something to do with missing privileges - rather with some timeouts. But I have no idea which one so far...

Comment: Currently, I struggle with this problem, tool. But I got the error on the end of my processing loop (in my case transferring data from one database to another with similar structure).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue recently. I got the "Invalid Operation on a closed object" but when I debug the code, it was the **OracleDataReader** that was closed and not the **OracleConnection**. My problem was the query `retuned` an empty response and the **DataReader** closes itself if there is no data. So my resolution was simply checking if the data reader have any rows by adding the following..

```
dro.Read();

if (dro.HasRows)
{
   //Do your 
}
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:**  While the information in this answer does not directly fix the issue in the original question, I found this question and the other answers very helpful in pinpointing the solution to another related scenario.

---

When changing from the unmanaged `Oracle.DataAccess` library to the managed `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` library, we found a very tricky difference.  Apparently, with the unmanaged library, the `dr.Read()` call is *not required* for the fetch to happen, but it most definitely *is required* with the managed library.

After switching to the managed library, all of our calls constructed similar to the example in the question needed to have `dr.Read()` added before trying to get any data out of the `dr` object, otherwise we would get the same "Invalid operation on a closed object" message.

Comment: This was exact was I searched for - Thenky you very much ... would give you more then one upvote if possible!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection String

Replace conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed with conn.State != ConnectionState.open

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was in this part of my code -

(dt is the object of DataTable in the below code samples)

```
using (var reader = lSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            dt.Load(reader);
                        }
                    }
```

When I removed the while part it got resolved. The working part now is like -

```
using (var reader = lSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(reader);                          
                    }
```