# How to fix “Invalid operation on a closed object” exception when trying to Read an OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm creating a web API using .Net Core and the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core plugin that accesses an Oracle database to retrieve a Blob field and return it as a byte array. I created a function (getBlobfromDB) that gets the Oracle connection string from an encrypted field on a SQL database, connects and uses an OraleDataReader to retrieve and return the Blob field. But when the OraleDataReader tries to Read the record, I'm getting this exception: "Invalid operation on a closed object".

When you search for this issue, the most relevant answer is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526111/oracle-invalidoperationexception-when-trying-to-select-from-a-table)

However, I'm 100% percent sure that user on the conn string has access since that is the schema owner, and I also tried adding the schema owner to the Select query (SELECT FIELD FROM SCHEMA_OWNER.TABLE WHERE ID = "") getting the same error

So I tried two other things, getting a different VARCHAR field from another table on the same database, still getting the same error; and trying on a different Oracle database and I was able to successfully retrieve the data. I noticed that the Oracle versions on the servers are different, 12.2 for the working one and 11.2 for the non-working, this may be the reason?  I don't know what else I can do or try, I'll appreciate any help/advice that you can give me

This is the simplified function

```
private OracleBlob getBlobfromDB(string sSystem, string sID)
        {
            string sSQL = String.Empty;
            string connString = String.Empty;
            OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sID) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sSystem) )
            {
                return null;
            }          

            sSQL = "SELECT BLOB_FIELD FROM TABLE WHERE ID = " + sID;
            connString = getConnectionString(sSystem); 

            try
            {
                using (oConn = new OracleConnection(connString))
                { 
                    oConn.Open();
                    OracleCommand oCom = new OracleCommand(sSQL, oConn);                   

                    OracleDataReader oDr = oCom.ExecuteReader();                    
                    if (oDr.HasRows)
                    {      
                        //I'm able to reach to this point before getting the exception
                        oDr.Read();
                        OracleBlob blob = oDr.GetOracleBlob(0);                        
                        // Clean up
                        oDr.Close();
                        oDr.Dispose();
                        oCom.Dispose();
                        return blob;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Clean up
                        oDr.Close();
                        oDr.Dispose();
                        oCom.Dispose();
                        return null;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                oConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to keep the reader and connection open until you've read the blob.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, no?

Comment: No, you're returning an object that can be used to read the blob contents, but you still haven't done it. Until you're done with that blob object you should keep everything open.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following you, what exactly is wrong on my code? Because I'm getting the exception at line 

oDr.Read();
 
even before I close the connection

Answer (score 0):

With the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` dependency you should not `Close()` the connection and do not use the `using` clause. It seems that the dependency itself closes the connection at will.

Remove: `using(){}` keyword and `oConn.Close()` from your code.

Comment: I'm surprised at the statement about removing the using() keyword. Without the closure of the Using clause, I don't see how the cleanup can be accomplished.

This link indicates that we should be coding the using() with Oracle connections: https://www.oracle.com/tools/technologies/quickstart-dotnet-for-oracle-database.html

Can you point us to a documentation page that instructs us to not code with using?

Comment: This is wrong an dangerous advice. Although it is managed, you still have to take care of disposing the underlying connection. Otherwise the driver has no clue when to do so. In fact, following this answer will over time exhaust all your connections in the pool and lead to errors very difficult to track down.